# My Liquid tag is not recognized by GitHub pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, katex

I used Jekyll 3.8.5 and built a blog on GitHub. I also used [Jekyll-Katex 0.3.0](https://github.com/linjer/jekyll-katex), a Jekyll plugin for easy server-side math rendering via KaTeX. Everything works fine on my local machine. But when I pushed it to GitHub, I got this: "Your site is having problems building: The tag Katexmm on line 11 in _posts/2019-01-22-ECDSA-and-Bitcoin-I.md is not a recognized Liquid tag."

"Katexmm" is a [liquid tag of Jekyll-Katex](https://github.com/linjer/jekyll-katex#katexmm), so I checked dependencies. [Jekyll-Katex 0.3.0 requires Jekyll ~> 3.8](https://github.com/linjer/jekyll-katex/blob/master/jekyll-katex.gemspec) while [GitHub Pages uses Jekyll 3.7.4](https://pages.github.com/versions/). I guess that's the problem.

What shall I do? 
One more thing: I want to use "katexmm", please don't suggest me to use Jekyll 3.7.4 instead of  3.8.5.
Thanks in advance.

I followed ashmaroli's suggestion, but still doesn't work. I tried Nelify and "Deploy failed":

```html
11:31:01 AM: Build ready to start
11:31:03 AM: build-image version: 84aca9ba39e0ee86ba194760fbfc51a808f62543
11:31:04 AM: buildbot version: 57d44fd1631cc3fff8b38fbaf88d3d04f946418a
11:31:04 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:31:04 AM: Starting to download cache of 254.7KB
11:31:04 AM: Finished downloading cache in 147.184771ms
11:31:04 AM: Starting to extract cache
11:31:04 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:31:04 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:31:04 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:31:04 AM: git clone https://github.com/Jun-Wang-2018/Blog
11:31:05 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/gh-pages
11:31:06 AM: Starting build script
11:31:06 AM: Installing dependencies
11:31:08 AM: Downloading and installing node v8.15.0...
11:31:08 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.15.0/node-v8.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
11:31:08 AM:      0.0%
11:31:08 AM: 
######
11:31:08 AM:                    8.4%
11:31:08 AM: 
#############################################
11:31:08 AM: ###                          66.8%
11:31:08 AM: 
######################################
11:31:08 AM: ################################## 100.0%
11:31:08 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
11:31:08 AM: Checksums matched!
11:31:11 AM: Now using node v8.15.0 (npm v6.4.1)
11:31:12 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
11:31:13 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
11:31:15 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
11:31:15 AM: Started restoring cached ruby gems
11:31:15 AM: Finished restoring cached ruby gems
11:31:15 AM: Installing gem bundle
11:31:15 AM: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
11:31:15 AM: Error during gem install
11:31:15 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:31:15 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:31:15 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:31:15 AM: Finished processing build request in 11.629358799s
```

I tried Cloudcannon and "Jekyll build failed":

```html
Syncing raw files... done
Checking existing local bundle state... failed
Loading gem cache... 
Checking gem cache (bundle_cache/A16MrNFnrU9wWPnsPr5G8PkR_kBFEHG0ytrPjGtZ7mQ.zip)... no cache

$ export JEKYLL_ENV="production"

$ ruby -v

ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]

$ bundle -v

Bundler version 1.16.6

$ bundle config --global jobs 4

Configured concurrent installs!

$ bundle install

Using local cacheable path...
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

Comment: Github pages supported gems : https://pages.github.com/versions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved, FINALLY. 
I used another static generator Hexo with an amazing theme "Next" and it works fine with KaTeX.

[My site snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6spC.png)

[My site](https://jun-wang-2018.github.io/MyBlog/en/ECDSA-and-Bitcoin-I/)

Two main steps to solve the problem:

Step 1. Install Hexo and deploy my site to GitHub

Step 2. Embed KaTex

There are some details in each step. I wrote two posts:
[Step 1](https://jun-wang-2018.github.io/MyBlog/en/hexo-and-github/), 
[Step 2](https://jun-wang-2018.github.io/MyBlog/en/hexo-and-katex/).

Answer (score 0):

Since GitHub Pages supports only a limited set of Ruby Gems (https://pages.github.com/versions/), the recommended way is to build locally and push the contents of your destination folder (`./_site` by default) to your remote for hosting.
However, that requires [a bit of work to set up](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/) since you already have a repository set up to build from the `master` branch.

The *relatively easier* route would be to ditch GitHub Pages entirely for a third-party player like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/), [Cloudcannon](https://cloudcannon.com/), etc depending on your use-case.

#### Netlify Deploy Gotchas

- `jekyll-katex-0.3.0` requires at least Ruby Version `2.5.1`. So, you'll have to configure Netlify to use that version. The easiest way is by defining an environment variable `RUBY_VERSION` with value set to `2.5.1`
- Another gotcha is the Bundler version. Netlify doesn't seem to be using / installing `Bundler-2.0`. So, either

  - generate a `Gemfile.lock` locally using an older version of Bundler, or
  - Remove existing `Gemfile.lock` from the repository. (Adding Gemfile.lock to a `.gitignore` file will prevent it from being committed back).
- *Netlify doesn't seem to work with `baseurl` config as expected. You'll have to set it to an empty string or `null`*

Comment: Thanks, ashmaroli. I tried your method, but it doesn't work. In cloudcannon, jekyll build failed. In Netlify, deploy failed.

Comment: What is the failure message in Netlify deploy log?

Comment: I refreshed my original post, see above.

Comment: The error is from Bundler version discrepancies. You can workaround that by removing `Gemfile.lock` from your repository.

Comment: I deleted Gemfile.lock, it's better, but still has an Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-katex or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-katex' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!

Comment: You have two `:jekyll_plugins` groups in your Gemfile. Perhaps merging them into one will help. Also, you can get a backtrace from errors when you run the build with `--trace` i.e. `bundle exec jekyll build --trace`

Comment: Thanks, ashmaroli, my site is deployed now. But when I click my post from my homepage, it says "404 Page not found :("

Comment: That's a different issue. I won't be able to debug till I get the URL to your published site.

Comment: It turns out that I have to use Bundler 2.0. If I use an older version of Bundler, My local site doesn't work at all.

Comment: Okay. For some reason, Netlify doesn't seem to work with `baseurl: '/Blog'`. So, I'd recommend resetting it and `url` to empty strings. i.e. `baseurl: ""`, `url: ""`

Comment: Thanks, ashmaroli. I'll just leave the problem there. Maybe several months later, GitHub will support Jekyll 3.8.0. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. While GitHub Pages *may* support Jekyll 3.8 in the future, there's *very little chance* that they'll support `jekyll-katex` plugin. So you might as well look for alternative routes.